# Adding new values to an enum through migration using the mssql dialect

Tags: javascript, sql-server, sequelize.js

I am trying to create a migration using sequelize that will add a new value to an enum.

We are using SQL-Server and have set the dialect to 'mssql' in the sequelize config.

Here is the code I have written that is not generating a valid SQL statement:

```
module.exports = {
  up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.changeColumn('myTable', 'myColumn', {
      type: Sequelize.ENUM('A', 'B', 'C', 'D'),
      allowNull: false
    });
  },

  down: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.changeColumn('myTable', 'myColumn', {
      type: Sequelize.ENUM('A', 'B', 'C'),
      allowNull: false
    });
  }
};
```

And here is the created SQL that is invalid

```
     ALTER TABLE [myTable] ALTER COLUMN [myColumn] VARCHAR(255) CHECK ([myColumn] IN(N'A', N'B', N'C', N'D'));
```

The code fails with `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'CHECK'`

I am not sure what else I have to add to the migration to make it work, or if this is even supported for my dialect after looking through the documentation and relevant github issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that MSSQL does not really support `ENUM` type. Instead, it creates a CHECK constraint and uses the `STRING` type.

The best solution is to first delete the existing CHECK constraint and then re-create it with the new definition: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/modify-check-constraints?view=sql-server-ver15#TsqlProcedure

Using Sequelize I didn't know anything about the created constraint which made it difficult to perform the above solution. So I decided to remove the ENUM type from the DB level and keep it on the model level